# No Society specified and Unused global options [apl,aps4]

Tags: revtex

I was wonder why I receive the following message.

```
Warning line 1 No Society specified, using generic APS style.
```

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[apl, aps4, twocolumn, superscriptaddress]{revtex4}
```

As far as I know I have specified apl style.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Jubobs For once, a MWE is not quite so important (you only need to add `\begin{document}` to the above so TeX writes to the log to see the message).

Comment: The apl style is not specified in a way recognised by revtex latex says `LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [apl,aps4].`

Comment: @JosephWrigt Yes, you're right. I initially thought that the warning was issued by the class because it expected the OP to redefine some macro in the preamble. I was wrong.

Answer (score 5):

If you look a little further through the log, you'll find it reads

```
Class revtex4 Warning: No Society specified, using generic APS style.

...

LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [apl,aps4].
```

Notice that neither `apl` nor `aps4` are recognised. Changing the input to

```
\documentclass[apl, aps, twocolumn, superscriptaddress]{revtex4}
```

removes the 'No Society' warning and gives

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [apl].
```

So the warning is telling you something: you're using option names that the class does not know, and that means it's falling back on a generic format.

Comment: Regarding that second warning, the class defines a macro called `\apl` but there doesn't seem to be a class option called `apl`.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling your document I get:

```
Class revtex4 Warning: No Society specified, using generic APS style.
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):    [apl,aps4].
```

You need to use [`revtex4-1`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1):

```
\documentclass[aip,apl,twocolumn,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}
Hi!
\end{document}
```

Comment: The option `aps4` still seems to be unknown, and fails if you give it before `aip`.